# Display some part of text in bold and some part in italic in SWT label

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have to show some warning message to the user like

"If you restore data the updated changes will be **lost**, So  *recheck* once"

In german language also I have to same string with bold and italic.

In both languages the dialog height and width should be same

```
public class BoldTextMessageDialog extends ZedisTrayDialog {

  private Composite container;
  private String firstSring;
  private String secondString;
  private String boldString;
  private Button restoreButton;
  private Button cancelButton;

  public BoldTextMessageDialog(Shell shell, String firstSring, String   secondString, String boldString) {
    super(shell);
    this.firstSring = firstSring;
    this.secondString = secondString;
    this.boldString = boldString;
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

    container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new FormLayout());
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);

    gd.heightHint = 300;
    gd.widthHint = 500;
    container.setLayoutData(gd);

    Label warningLabel = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    warningLabel.setImage(parent.getDisplay().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING));

    FormData fd = new FormData();
    fd.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    fd.top = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
    warningLabel.setLayoutData(fd);

    Label firstLabel = new Label(container, SWT.WRAP);
    firstLabel.setText(firstSring);

    fd = new FormData();
    fd.left = new FormAttachment(warningLabel, 10);
    fd.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    fd.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    firstLabel.setLayoutData(fd);

    Label secLabel = new Label(container, SWT.WRAP);
    secLabel.setText(boldString);
    secLabel.setFont(FontCache.getBoldFont());

    fd = new FormData();
    fd.top = new FormAttachment(0, 25);
    fd.left = new FormAttachment(0, 48);
    secLabel.setLayoutData(fd);

    Label thirdLabel = new Label(container, SWT.WRAP);
    thirdLabel.setText(secondString);

    fd = new FormData();
    fd.top = new FormAttachment(0, 25);
    fd.left = new FormAttachment(secLabel, 3);
    fd.right = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
    thirdLabel.setLayoutData(fd);

    return parent;
  }

}
```

This is what I tried, but the problem is for german and english both italic and bold text are coming at different places, so for same size they are not suitable. If I use different sizes its ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display styled text in SWT you can use the `Browser` widget or `StyledText` widget. In both cases you likely need to change the default appearance and behavior to be label-like (i.e. background color, read-only)

**Browser Widget**

```
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.NONE );
browser.setText( "If you restore data the changes will be <b>lost</b>, So <i>recheck</i> once" );
```

**Styled Text**

```
StyledText text = new StyledText( parent, SWT.NONE );
text.setText( "If you restore data the changes will be lost, So recheck once" );
```

Through `StyleRange`s you can define how portions of the text should be formatted. A style range has a `start` and a `length` that specifies the part of the text it is applied to and a `TextStyle` to control the style attributes to be applied. To let the first char appear bold the code would look like this:

```
StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange( 0, 1, null, null, SWT.BOLD );
text.setStyleRanges( new StyleRange[]{ styleRange } );
```

**FormText**

A further option, if you have a dependency on `org.eclipse.ui.forms` already, is to use the `FormText` widget. It supports HTML like markup within the text, similar to the browser widget. This is probably the most label-like widget but drags in an additional dependency.