# JFace message dialog: inline text coloring

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

What I would like to do is to open a confirm dialog, some of which's text is colored.

Example:

```
MessageDialog.openConfirm(shell, "title", "message a b c foobar");
```

Let's say I want to display "message" and "foobar" in regular black, but "a", "b" and "c" should be differently colored (e.g. red, green, blue).
Like this: [image]

Is that possible using `MessageDialog.openConfirm`? If yes, how, and if not, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried HTML text?

Comment: putting `<html>` in the beginning didn't help, it just got displayed as plain text (I didn't try coloring, but `<html>` and `<br>` were displayed as plain text, soooooo ... :/). This ain't swing, (un?)fortunately.

Comment: You'll have to roll your own dialog. You could use `StyledText` to do the colouring.

Comment: See here for a summary of the options at hand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874579/display-some-part-of-text-in-bold-and-some-part-in-italic-in-swt-label

Comment: See also here for how to replace the contents of a `MessageDialog`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374160/add-link-to-messagedialog-message/29374934

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend creating a subclass of [`MessageDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FMessageDialog.html) and using [`StyledText`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html) for the message. Like the comments suggest, you can override the `createMessageArea(Composite)` method. You can borrow the code from [`IconAndMessageDialog`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FIconAndMessageDialog.html), and instead of a `Label`, create a `StyledText` using [`StyleRange`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyleRange.html) objects given in the constructor:

```
@Override
protected Control createMessageArea(final Composite composite) {
    // ...
    if (message != null) {
        styledText = new StyledText(composite, SWT.NONE);
        styledText.setEditable(false);
        styledText.setEnabled(false);
        styledText.setBackground(composite.getBackground());
        styledText.setText(message);
        styledText.setStyleRanges(styleRanges);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()
                .align(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING)
                .grab(true, false)
                .hint(convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.MINIMUM_MESSAGE_AREA_WIDTH), SWT.DEFAULT)
                .applyTo(styledText);
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can also create a new static method comparable to `MessageDialog.openConfirm(Shell, String, String)`:

```
public static boolean openConfirm(final Shell parent, final String title, final String message, final StyleRange[] styleRanges) {
    final MessageDialog dialog = new StyledTextMessageDialog(parent, title, message, styleRanges);
    return dialog.open() == 0;
}
```

[image]

---

Full `StyledTextMessageDialog` class:

```
public class StyledTextMessageDialog extends MessageDialog {

    private static final String[] DIALOG_BUTTON_LABELS = new String[]{
            IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL,
            IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL
    };
    private static final int DEFAULT_INDEX = 0;

    private final StyleRange[] styleRanges;
    private StyledText styledText;

    public StyledTextMessageDialog(final Shell parent, final String title, final String message, final StyleRange[] styleRanges) {
        super(parent, title, null, message, MessageDialog.QUESTION, DIALOG_BUTTON_LABELS, DEFAULT_INDEX);
        if (styleRanges == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("style ranges cannot be null");
        }
        this.styleRanges = styleRanges;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createMessageArea(final Composite composite) {
        final Image image = getQuestionImage();
        if (image != null) {
            imageLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
            image.setBackground(imageLabel.getBackground());
            imageLabel.setImage(image);
            addAccessibleListeners(imageLabel);
            GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()
                    .align(SWT.CENTER, SWT.BEGINNING)
                    .applyTo(imageLabel);
        }
        if (message != null) {
            styledText = new StyledText(composite, SWT.NONE);
            styledText.setEditable(false);
            styledText.setEnabled(false);
            styledText.setBackground(composite.getBackground());
            styledText.setText(message);
            styledText.setStyleRanges(styleRanges);
            GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()
                    .align(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING)
                    .grab(true, false)
                    .hint(convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.MINIMUM_MESSAGE_AREA_WIDTH), SWT.DEFAULT)
                    .applyTo(styledText);
        }
        return composite;
    }

    private void addAccessibleListeners(final Label label) {
        label.getAccessible().addAccessibleListener(new AccessibleAdapter() {
            public void getName(final AccessibleEvent event) {
                final String accessibleMessage = JFaceResources.getString("question");
                if (accessibleMessage != null) {
                    event.result = accessibleMessage;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static boolean openConfirm(final Shell parent, final String title, final String message, final StyleRange[] styleRanges) {
        final MessageDialog dialog = new StyledTextMessageDialog(parent, title, message, styleRanges);
        return dialog.open() == 0;
    }

}
```

Note that the private methods are taken from `IconAndMessageDialog`, with a few liberties taken since we're expecting a confirm/question dialog.

Example usage:

```
public class StyledTextMessageDialogTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        final String title = "Hello, stylish dialog!";
        final String message = "message a b c foobar";
        final StyleRange[] styleRanges = new StyleRange[]{
                new StyleRange(8, 1, display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED), null),
                new StyleRange(10, 1, display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN), null),
                new StyleRange(12, 1, display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE), null)
        };
        StyledTextMessageDialog.openConfirm(shell, title, message, styleRanges);
    }

}
```